# How does Kant substantiate the noumenal world?

Tags: kant, empiricism, perception

This is a new idea for me and I have struggled understanding Kant. How does Kant substantiate the noumenal world?

..Also, is their an online text or online video someone can reference me to that further dives into the noumenal world?

Comment: this is very helpful and eye opening, but to be frank I will need to read over this more to understand it. @Conifold

Comment: He does not substantiate it at all (well, maybe in terms of practical faith). That's kind of the point of the difference between noumenal and real.